# Is this code vulnerable to a CSRF attack?

Tags: php, attack-prevention

I am utilizing tokens to protect from a CSRF attack but to make the "back" button still work I reuse old tokens if they are set.  Does this still provide CSRF protection or can an attacker just set the "CSRFtokeneditcustomer" cookie to be somthing like "hello" and easily bypass this protection?

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["CSRFtokeneditcustomer"])){
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));//preventCSRF
        setcookie("CSRFtokeneditcustomer", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24,'/','',true,true);
    }else{
        $token =$_COOKIE["CSRFtokeneditcustomer"];
    }
    ?>
    <form id="editForm" method="post" action="<?= ROOT."/".$_SESSION['PAGE']['REQUEST']."/" ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <div><input type="hidden" name="action" value="editcustomer" /></div>
        <div><input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" /></div>
        <div><input type="hidden" name="fullload" value="<?= (($_REQUEST['fullload']) ? 1 : 0); ?>" /></div>
        <div><input type="hidden" name="edit" value="<?= $this->data['id']; ?>" /></div>
        <div><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?= $this->data['id']; ?>" /></div>
        <input name="CSRFtokeneditcustomer" type="hidden" value="<? echo $token?>"/>
        <div id="cms_mainform">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attacker cannot set cookies for a CSRF attack.  The only thing the attacker can do is force the victim browser to make a request to the target webserver.  Assuming you've got code server-side which is comparing the "CSRFtokeneditcustomer" field in the form and comparing it to the value in the cookie, you should be safe from CSRF.